# Pop Up desconto

Tags: popup

Olá, eu tenho uma página de vendas e estou desenvolvendo um pop up que oferece um desconto quando o usuário move o mouse pra tentar fechar a página! não quero que o usuário fique preso no meu site, só quero que abra o pop up quando ele tentar fechar, oferecendo um desconto.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é imoral, e se você fosse meu filho e eu te pegasse tentando fazer esse tipo de coisa em um site você estaria fora do meu testamento.

Enfim... você mencionou em um comentário na outra resposta um determinado site. **O que o site faz não é abrir um popup, mas sim um modal**. Isso é diferente de abrir um popup pois não interfere com o comportamento do navegador e não abre uma aba nova.

O tal site usa uma biblioteca chamada [**Ouibounce**, que você pode encontrar no Github](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce). O que o código da biblioteca faz é uma função que verifica a coordenada Y do cursor do mouse (que para o Javascript é relativo à janela). Se o mouse estiver a menos de uma quantidade de pixels do topo da janela, ele manda abrir um modal.

Note que isso significa que o modal abre se você mover o mouse para qualquer ponto mais alto do navegador, como outras abas ou mesmo um menu. Não vai disparar necessariamente apenas quando alguém mover o mouse para fechar ou trocar de aba, nem vai abrir o modal se o usuário utilizar atalhos de teclado. Também não vai funcionar em navegadores mobile ou que utilizam experiências de usuário diferentes, por motivos óbvios.

Se você não tiver alma nem ética você pode modificar o código do Ouibounce para abrir um popup mesmo ao invés de um modal.

Comment: Não entendi por que é imoral, eu vejo só uma página oferecendo desconto, nada além, me explica a parte imoral

Comment: @Fabio popups são desagradáveis e podem ser vetores de ataques. Abrir popups para fazer ofertas e propagandas é anti-ético. É por causa disso que hoje os navegadores bloqueiam certos tipos de popup por padrão. Isso também provoca, por exemplo, a necessidade de você ter que autorizar popups manualmente em determinados sites que tomaram decisões ruins de design. **Note que o site que você indicou no comentário da outra resposta não abre popups.** A biblioteca que ele utiliza abre **modais**, que são algo completamente inofensivo (se não em estética, ao menos em segurança).

Answer (score 0):

e impossivel fazer qualquer coisa quando o usuario tentar fechar uma aba ou a janela, tu pode tentar usar o evento beforeunload que funciona quando o usuario clicar num link, ou tentar acessar outro endereco na mesma aba pela barra de enderecos. Ou tambem pode tentar adicionar um evento mousemove e quando o mouse tiver fora voce faz o que voce quer:

```
addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (e.offsetY < 0) // acredito que nesse momento seja quando o mouse estiver perto do botao de fechar a pagina
});
```

Comment: Eu posso colocar um link aqui de exemplo? pra você ver o que eu quero.

Comment: pode sim, a vontade.

Comment: https://slimcaps.com.br/produtos da uma olhada ai, quando eu vou na direção de fechar o site, aparece um pop up

Comment: @Fabio Me parece que o site usa o evento "mouseout".

Comment: verdade e isso mesmo, ignora o mousemove.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!